# I set up a Drupal project in ddev and I get a PDOException when hitting the project URL

Tags: drupal, ddev

I see this when going to my project I just set up in ddev: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.semaphore' doesn't exist:` and `Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

- Hit the /install.php URL to install (like `http://mysite.ddev.local/install.php`) or
- Import a database with `ddev import-db`

The problem here is that most Drupal versions assume that if a settings.php is configured and a db exists (and ddev does that on config), that it will have something useful in it, so it doesn't redirect by default to /install.php.